# Ошибка при переводе строки в число

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть ответ сервера в виде строки. При попытке перевести его в число выпадает NaN, подскажите почему?

```
webix.ajax().get("/api/?id=CountArtSKU").then(function(data){
          //response
          console.log(data.text());
          var countAllSKU = data.text();
          console.log(typeof countAllSKU);
          console.log(parseInt(countAllSKU, 10));
          console.log(parseInt("83880"));
        });
```

на скрине вывод в консоль[image: скрин]

[image: если удалить .text()]

[image: скрин]

Comment: Вангую кавычки в тексте

Comment: `console.log("[" + data.text() + "]");` - ?

Comment: Можно развернуть json на втором скрине?

Comment: я все еще жду ответа на свой вопрос )

Comment: Попробуйте сначала почистить строку от лишних символов через str.replace(/\D+/g, ''); например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тебя в строке кавычки:

[image: скриншот]

Парси так (хотя лучше бы исправить сервер):

```js
var s = '"123"'
var x = +s.replace(/^"|"$/g, "")

console.log(x)
```